# RSS feed's content doesn't show in RSS readers

Tags: web, rss, svelte, sveltekit

I have created a SvelteKit application which serves an RSS feed at https://learn.flucoma.org/explore/rss.xml. The feed is valid, according to the W3C validator. https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.flucoma.org%2Fexplore%2Frss.xml

However, in any RSS reader I have tested with, the content of the website does not render in the preview window while many other blogs and feeds with an almost identical RSS XML structure do. How can I make the content of each article under https://learn.flucoma.org/explore/ (which are the ones populating the RSS feed) have their content displayed accordingly?

---

For additional information, I have added the server endpoint which returns the XML. note that the date is currently placeholder.

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { db } from '$lib/app';

export const prerender = true;

const siteURL = 'https://learn.flucoma.org'
 
export function GET({ }) {
    const posts = db.filter(x => x.flair == 'podcast')
    const render = (posts) =>
    (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" 
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        >
    <channel>
    <title>FluCoMa Learn Podcasts</title>
    <description>The latest FluCoMa podcasts, hosted by Jacob Hart with artists working with machine learning and machine listening technology in their artistic practices.</description>
    <language>en-gb</language>
    <link>https://learn.flucoma.org</link>
    <atom:link href="${siteURL}/explore/rss.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
    
    ${posts
    .map(
        (post) => `<item>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">${siteURL}${post.url}</guid>
    <title>${post.title}</title>
    <link>${siteURL}${post.url}</link>
    <description>${post.blurb}</description>
    <author>info@flucoma.org</author>
    <pubDate>${new Date(1993, 1).toUTCString()}</pubDate>
    </item>`
    )
    .join('')
    }

    </channel>
    </rss>
    `)

    const xml = render(posts);
    
    return new Response(xml, {
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, s-maxage=3600',
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
          }
    });
}
```

The `db` is a variable holding an array of articles with links, information, title, author etc.

Comment: You could compare differences more precisely with e.g. https://svelte.dev/blog/rss.xml that also generates a feed with SvelteKit itself? Perhaps it'll show the culprit?

Comment: As a matter of a fact, I can successfully import it in Feedly

Comment: PS. It would be nice to add some relevant bits of your current RSS and article pages in code to this question by editing. That way if you ever fix the linked sites, the question will still be relevant and indexable for others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: I added some additional context such as the server endpoint code. @Jeroen

Comment: Do you mean that the content of the post(youtube, talking, links etc.) show up in Feedly @carlosV2?

Comment: @james oh, apologies. I just checked that it recognised the URL as an RSS which it does but now that I open the posts, it doesn't seem to show any content other than a brief text description. However, to be fair, the multimedia content doesn't show in the page's source code. Have you tried adding some HTML for it? I'm afraid I really don't know how to build an RSS tho but [this RSS](https://www.xatakamovil.com/feedburner.xml) has rich descriptions.